# Ajax is not working properly with each function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a function with drag&drop HTML5, so. I need to save 2 elements dropped in different div element, so, I made a structure to save them, all is working, except one thing, my ajax tequest is not been working properly. I read the elements via .each() function, I detect if I've been inserted an element, if not, I inserted and get the ID from DB, then, in teory, the each function pass to the second element and make the same process but, if I already insert an element before, took that ID from div "data-id" tag and update the registry in my DB.
But the ajax request make two process separately, I mean, make 2 rounds, and then insert that 2 elements separately, and I get 2 IDs, not 1. This is my code.

```
function drop(ev)
        {
            ev.preventDefault();
            var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
            ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
            $(".team").removeClass('selected');
            var torneo  = $(ev.target).attr("data-tournament");
            var jornada = $(ev.target).attr("data-jornada");
            var partido = $(ev.target).attr("data-partido");
            var undef   = 0;
            if($(".match-container-"+partido).find("div.posiciones img").length==2)
            {
                $(".match-container-"+partido).find("div.posiciones img").each(function()
                {
                    /*if(typeof $(".match-container-"+partido).find("div.posiciones img").attr('data-equipo')== 'undefined')
                    {*/
                        alert("El parent de: "+$(this).attr('data-tooltip')+" es: "+$(this).parent().attr("data-equipo"));
                        $(".match-container-"+partido).find("div.posiciones img").attr('data-equipo',$(this).parent().attr("data-equipo"));
                    /*}
                    else
                    {
                        alert($(this).parent().attr("data-equipo"));
                    }*/
                    var equipo  = $(this).attr("data-equipo");
                    var team    = $(this).attr("data-id");
                    console.log("entro al igual a 2");
                    console.log("FOUNDED:"+$(".match-container-"+partido).find("div.posiciones img").length);
                    /*$(".match-number-container-"+partido).removeClass('blue')
                    $(".match-number-container-"+partido).addClass('green')*/
                    if($(".match-container-"+partido).find("div.posiciones img").length==2)
                    {
                        $(".match-container-"+partido).find("div.posiciones img").attr('draggable','false');
                        $(".match-container-"+partido).find("div.posiciones").attr('ondrop', 'false');
                        $(".match-container-"+partido).find("div.posiciones").attr('ondragover', 'false');
                    }

                    alert("Se insertará el partido: "+partido+", de la jornada: "+jornada+" del: "+torneo+" con: "+$(this).attr('data-tooltip')+" de ID "+team);
                    if(typeof $(".match-container-"+partido).attr('data-id')== 'undefined')
                    {
                        alert("Entro al AJAX de vacío"+$(".match-container-"+partido).attr('data-id'));
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '<?=base_url();?>jornada/insertarPartido',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: {param1: jornada,
                                    param2: torneo,
                                    param3: team,
                                    param4: undef,
                                    param5: equipo,
                                    param6: $(this).attr('data-tooltip')},
                            success:function(json)
                            {
                                if(json.response_code=="200")
                                {
                                    alert("insertado");
                                    $(".match-container-"+partido).attr('data-id',data.response_id);
                                }
                                console.log(data);
                            },
                            error:function(xhre)
                            {
                                console.log("error");
                                console.log(xhre)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '<?=base_url();?>jornada/insertarPartido',
                            type: 'POST',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: {param1: jornada,
                                    param2: torneo,
                                    param3: team,
                                    param4: $(".match-container-"+partido).attr('data-id'),
                                    param5: equipo},
                            success:function(json)
                            {
                                if(json.response_code=="200")
                                {
                                    alert("insertado");
                                }
                                console.log(data);
                            },
                            error:function(xhre)
                            {
                                console.log("error");
                                console.log(xhre)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                });
            }
```

I hope you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve this.
I had to add this attribute to the ajax request:

```
async: false,
```

I was reading ajax documentation, and we can use this conf, if we want to send two request in the same block.